# Listitems and if Statements with charts

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a chart in which i want to be able to add or remove lines based on a checkboxlist. 
To this end i came up with this code:

```
        foreach (ListItem lstitem in CBLYear.Items)
    {

        if (lstitem.Value == "2014")
        {
            Chart3.Series["2014"].XValueMember = "Month";
            Chart3.Series["2014"].YValueMembers = "2014";
        }
        if (lstitem.Value == "2013")
        {
            Chart3.Series["2013"].XValueMember = "Month";
            Chart3.Series["2013"].YValueMembers = "2013";
        }
        if (lstitem.Value == "2012")
        {
            Chart3.Series["2012"].XValueMember = "Month";
            Chart3.Series["2012"].YValueMembers = "2012";
        }
        if (lstitem.Value == "2011")
        {
            Chart3.Series["2011"].XValueMember = "Month";
            Chart3.Series["2011"].YValueMembers = "2011";
        }
        if (lstitem.Value == "2010")
        {
            Chart3.Series["2010"].XValueMember = "Month";
            Chart3.Series["2010"].YValueMembers = "2010";
        }
        if (lstitem.Value == "2009")
        {
            Chart3.Series["2009"].XValueMember = "Month";
            Chart3.Series["2009"].YValueMembers = "2009";
        }
    }
```

On page load nothing shows up on the graph (as wanted). However once click any one of the items all the series show up not just the one i clicked why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `else if` from 2nd condition, you should use switch statement as in your code you are checking many conditions, in switch it will execute only the particular case

```
switch(Convert.ToString(lstitem.Value))
{
    case"":
        {
            // put all your conditions in cases 
        }
        break;
    default : 
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the entire items collection, so of course each series will show up.

You need to check the "Selected" property instead. You can do this easily using LINQ:

```
foreach (ListItem lstitem in CBLYear.Items.Where(l => l.Selected))
{
  ....
}
```

See the MSDN Documentation: [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Specifically the "Introduction" section)

Comment: I am new to programming and not used to LINQ. Can you explain Where(l => l.Selected)) my computer flags it.